# Define subdomain with apache ServerName using FritzBox

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a server with apache2 connected with my FritzBox, which does port forwarding on 80 and 443 and is reachable from the outside net via `<MYFRITZ>.myfritz.net`.

I can access a simple html, if I put `<MYFRITZ>.myfritz.net` in my browser using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MYFRITZ.myfritz.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/404

    <Directory /var/www/404/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/404-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/404-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to use another vhost to access another html via a subdomain using this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.MYFRITZ.myfritz.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/404b

    <Directory /var/www/404b/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/404b-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/404b-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

But entering `test.MYFRITZ.myfritz.net` into my browser results in "This site can’t be reachedtest.MYFRITZ.myfritz.net’s DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem.
DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE".

Both `/var/www/404` and `/var/www/404b/` exist (`404b` is simply a copy of `404`).
I thought using `ServerName` would allow to define a subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

`test.MYFRITZ.myfritz.net’s DNS address could not be found` is a clear diagnostic that tells you what the problem is: there is no A-record definition of `test.MYFRITZ.myfritz.net` in your DNS. Add that record, or a CNAME for it that points test at MYFRITZ, and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

The Fritz!Box supports two types of port forwardings, regular port forwardings and so called "MyFritz-Shares". In my experience only for MyFritz-Shares a DNS record in the format `hostname.MYFRITZ.myfritz.net` is created automatically. For regular port forwardings you need to set up a third party DynDNS service yourself.

Make sure your port forwarding is a MyFritz-Share.

Since myfritz.net is controlled by AVM and you can't setup any subdomain records you like you need to either make do with what the Fritz!Box provides or you set up another domain, for example CNAME records that point to your myfritz address.